# How to align text left in centered object

Tags: html, css

I've got the following code:

```
<center><div class="body">
<span style="margin-left:5px;text-align:left;">A text</span>
</div></center>
```

The text-align:left; isn't working. I've also tried margin: 0px auto; and that also didn't work.

Please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `display: block` on span

```css
.body span{margin-left:5px;text-align:left; display: block;}
```

```html
<center><div class="body">
<span>A text</span>
</div></center>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code:

```
<center>
   <div class="body">
     <div style="margin-left: 5px; text-align: left;">A text</div>
   </div>
</center>
```

However `<center>` tag is deprecated in HTML5 bcz it is related with alignment of content for which its better to use CSS..
A better approach is as follows:

```
<div class="body">
    <span>A text</span>
</div>

.body {
    text-align: center;
}
.body span {
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a SPAN in this case, I would use a DIV or a P. A SPAN element is not for showing lots of content and you can not put other block elements inside the SPAN otherwise it won't validate. I only say that because I misused the SPAN element for years by myself ;).